# 'loading' is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have this code to increment a jQuery UI progressbar but when I open this in Firefox, Firebug shows a error every time the setInterval function runs.

```
// show progress on progressbar
$(function() {
    $( "#loading" ).progressbar({
        value: 0
    });
});

//increment progressbar
var progressBar = $('#loading'),
    width = loading.width();

var interval = setInterval(function() {

width += 1;

loading.css('width', width + '%');

if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        loadContent();
    }
}, 75);
```

The exact error I get from Firebug is:

```
loading is not defined
width = loading.width();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare `progressBar` but never use it.
I think this is a mistake and you want to declare `loading`

```
//increment progressbar
var loading = $('#loading'),
width = loading.width();
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks. Im not that good with javascript (still learning) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('#loading').css('width', width + '%');`. The `loading` var isn't defined.

Comment: Could you post exactly where I put it, I'm having some issues.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to call it with jQuery:

```
$('#loading').width();
```

You never set the variable loading. It can be done this way:

```
var loading = $('#loading');
```